# React linting errors when using bower and xo-react

Tags: reactjs, eslint

I have a React app. I am using [xo-react](https://github.com/sindresorhus/eslint-config-xo-react) for my linter configuration.
When I use `webpack` or `systemjs` as module manager, everything is fine but when I use bower I have issues like `react/jsx-no-undef`or `react-in-jsx-scope` coming from my JSX templates.

Example:

```
return (
    <Title/>
);
```

throws `'Title' is not defined` (`react/jsx-no-undef`)

Answer (score 0):

Typically, when using Webpack you'll do `import Title from './title.js';` or `var Title = require('./title.js');`. The linter can see that `Title` is then declared in that scope. For SystemJS, the equivalent would be `System.import('./title.js').then(function (Title) { /* Title exists here */ });`, and again there's a `Title` in scope. Bower using just `<script>` tags relies on globals, but the linter doesn't know about them unless you tell it. There are two ways to do that:

1. Inline comments: `/*global Title*/`
2. Add them to the `globals` section of your `.eslintrc`: `{ "globals": { "Title": true } }`

See the documentation on [specifying globals](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-globals) for more.